# error: ";" expected before "void"

Tags: c++, header

This might be stupid but I'm getting an error saying `"; expected before "void" in the header file."`

```
#ifndef PA1_H_INCLUDED
#define PA1_H_INCLUDED

void magicSquare(int n);

#endif // PA1_H_INCLUDED
```

Isn't this the correct way to write the header?

This is the main, where `pa1` is the name of the header

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std
 #include "pa1.h"

int main(){
cout<<"Enter the size of magic square: ";
int n;
cin>>n;                                  //Enter the size of the magic square
if(n%2!=0 && n>=3 && n<=15){             //If the number is odd and between 3 and 15 run the program
int m=n;
magicSquare(m);
}
else{
cout<<"Number is not odd or is out of range."<<endl;   
}
return 0;
}
```

And this is the `magicSquare()` function

```
void magicSquare(int n){
int square[n][n];                     
for (int i=0; i<n; i++){              
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    square[i][j]=0;
}
}
int a=0;
int b=n/2;                            
for(int c=1; c<=n*n; c++){            
if(a<0 && b>=n){                  
    a=a+2;
    b--;
}
if (a<0)                          
    a=n-1;
if(b>=n)                          
    b=0;
if(square[a][b]){                 

    a=a+2;
    b--;
}
square[a][b]=c;
 a--, b++;                        
}

 cout<<"Magic square #1 is:"<<endl;
 for (int a=0; a<n; a++){             
 for (int b=0; b<n; b++){
    cout<<square[a][b]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;
}
}
```

In the `magicsquare()` function, I first created the magic square by assigning each value to the correct the position with the various conditions needed to create it and after that I printed the square. 
I can get it to work only if I write the `;` before `void` in the header

Comment: That header, by itself, is fine. Where do you include it? What code do you have above that inclusion? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: The problem is in whatever you included before that header.

Comment: Take a close look at the line before you `#include "pa.h"`. Isn't it something missing at the end of it?

Comment: I just realized I forgot the semicolon for using namespace std

Comment: Yeah thank you some programmer dude

Comment: A better fix for that error is to completely remove `using namespace std`.

Answer (score 2):

The mistake is simple; you forgot to add a semicolon before the:

```
using namespace std;
```

line. When you add that, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there is an unrecognized character before this line. Such as unicode white space. Make sure this line is empty.

BTW, if errors in any other header file included before this file will lead to this issue too.

In your case, you have lost ';' after 'using namespace std'.